# CSS Position:fixed in Web OS apps

Tags: css, web-applications, cordova, webos, css-position

Can I make "position:fixed" work in some way under Web OS browser?

I made a cross-platform app using Phone Gap that works in iOS and Android. I fixed the scroll problem on those platforms using iScroll, but this library doesn't work in WebOS.

For example, Facebook app has a titlebar fixed on the top of the page.

The idea for my app is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KoDM.png

Comment: Can you provide some code?  I think it's known that there is an issue with this because things don't stay put like the should on sites like gmail, either.  It might work in webos 2.x, though.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

https://github.com/neave/touch-scroll